# Replace images with alternate text html agility pack

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-agility-pack

I need to parse HTML for images and replace those tags with a new tag that just has the text that is contained in the alternate. Can someone show how to do this with both linq and standard usage?

I've using a linq sample now to replace paragraphs. But, I'm getting a read only error.

```
    HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(html);      
    IEnumerable<HtmlNode> paragraphs = doc.DocumentNode.DescendantNodes().Where(p => p.Name.ToLower() == "p");
    foreach (HtmlNode p in paragraphs)
    {
        p.InnerText = "Hello World";
    }
```

Also is there an easy way to transfer it back to text? I.e Output as string

This is what I have which doesn't work

```
MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream();
doc.Save(outStream);


outStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader( outStream );
string text = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var images = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img");
if (images != null)
{
    foreach (HtmlNode image in images)
    {
        var alt = image.GetAttributeValue("alt", "");
        var nodeForReplace = HtmlTextNode.CreateNode(alt);
        image.ParentNode.ReplaceChild(nodeForReplace, image);
    }
}

var sb = new StringBuilder();
using (var writer = new StringWriter(sb))
{
    doc.Save(writer);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you show me how to save the document back to a string? I've updated code above with what I have. It doesn't work.